# Playing music/mp3 on Ubuntu Phone

Tags: ubuntu-touch, mp3

Received my Bq Ubuntu phone yesterday, finally got around to playing with it today, and one of the first things I've noticed is that it doesn't seem to play any of my mp3's that are on my sd card.

The music app detects all the songs fine, and the play bar progresses (for a lot of the songs, some it doesn't offer the choice to play), but no sound comes out, either via speakers or headphones.

Now looking at some [ubuntu docs](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RestrictedFormats), mp3's are restricted by default, is that still the case on the phone OS?

(Apologies if not quite the right place to ask, I'd ask on the sub-reddit, but all tech support (which this could be classed as?) needs to come from here)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you try to check if you was affected by this [*volume muted* bug](https://github.com/kenvandine/pathwind/issues/6) ?

It happens when you play the game **PathWind** or **Machines vs Machines**, and mute the in-game volume. It will also mute the system volume whitch is a bug. This bug is now tracked at the link above.

**Steps to fix it:**

Simply launch the game PathWind on the phone, and check the setting of the game, in sound, and unmute. Should fix it.

**Other known reason**

If you are on the *devel-proposed* channel, you might be affected by [this bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gst-plugins-good1.0/+bug/1436162).

Comment: For what it's worth, I'm the one who raised that bug, and the inability to hear any sound from the Music app was exactly what led me to find it.

Comment: Thanks! I would never have found it, I'd uninstalled PathWind, so was unlikely to come across the fix naturally