# BQ Ubuntu Phone no sound when playing media in apps or via web apps

Tags: sound, phone

I have an annoying issue with the BQ phone at present in that whatever media I play either via you-tube, Music app etc I get no sound either through the speaker or via headphones.

Message/Notifications/Phone sounds are working fine.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you try to check if you was affected by this [volume muted bug](https://github.com/kenvandine/pathwind/issues/6) ?

It happens when you play the game PathWind, and mute the volume. It will mute the system volume.

Steps to fix it:

Simply launch the game PathWind on the phone, and check the setting of the game, in sound, and unmute it on the tached note symbol. Should fix it.

copied from [Playing music/mp3 on Ubuntu Phone](https://askubuntu.com/questions/600594/playing-music-mp3-on-ubuntu-phone?rq=1)

Comment: Thanks a million! Works now. Guess my searching skills need honing.